# According to GNOME guidelines, should git messages end with a full stop, or not?

Tags: git, coding-standards

According to GNOME guidelines, how sentences should be written in Git messages?

Should sentence in git commit message start with upper-case letter and end with a full stop, or lower-case without a full stop? What is the recommendation?

Btw. I'm asking about English, not Chinese.

Comment: Messages are written in English (or French, Chinese etc), so follow the rules of that language to make them readable to other people.

Comment: Read: [A guide to writing GIT commit messages](https://blogs.gnome.org/danni/2011/10/25/a-guide-to-writing-git-commit-messages/).

Comment: From a technical standpoint it doesn't matter at all. From a social standpoint, it matters if your team thinks it matters.

Comment: I'm asking about English, not Chinese.

Comment: Btw. It's not opinion-based, since GNOME and Git guidelines are very strict and I'm asking about these specific standards. Please refer to the answer.

Comment: @kenorb, Your question is currently confusing. You mention GNOME in the body, but not the title. Are you specifically asking about GNOME guidelines, or more generally. Oh and "Those are only recommended guidelines and maintainers can feel free to adopt other guidelines" doesn't sound very strict to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GNOME commit style guideline](https://wiki.gnome.org/Git/CommitMessages), the first line should of the commit message be a short description (ideally no more than 72 characters) and it should **not** end up with a full stop.

In summary:

> First line (the brief description) must only be one sentence and **should start with a capital letter** unless it starts with a lowercase symbol or identifier. **Don't use a trailing period** either.